# how to fix timeout error in web application

Tags: java, web, weblogic

I have a web application which is processing some data on server side. The problem is that if I have a big amount of data, I will get a timeout. 
Can anyone tell me how to increase the browser timeout exception.[during timeout exception I can see the logs and confirm that application is still processing the request] but browser is showing time out error

Technology: Basically application running in web logic portal application. 
Web logic 10.3 server + JSF + java

Answer (score 0):

**Tunneling Client Timeout in weblogic configuration**

If the number of seconds set in this attribute have elapsed since the client last sent a request to the server (in response to a reply), then the server regards the client as dead, and terminates the HTTP tunnel connection. The server checks the elapsed time at the interval specified by this attribute, when it would otherwise respond to the client's request.

Default is 40 seconds; valid range is 10 to 900 seconds.

You can do this by follwoing steps:

**Before you begin**

The server instance for which you configure the HTTP protocol does not need to be running.

*To configure the HTTP protocol:*

If you have not already done so, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Lock & Edit (see Use the Change Center).

In the left pane of the Console, expand Environment and select Servers.

On the Summary of Servers page, select the server instance you want to configure.

Select Protocols > HTTP and update as needed. See Configuration Options.
Click Save.

To enable tunneling of connections, select Protocols > General:
Select Enable Tunneling.

Provide values for Tunneling Client Ping and Tunneling Client Timeout.

Note: These settings apply to all protocols in the server's default network configuration that support tunneling.

configure value as 900 seconds max,

Click Save.

To activate these changes, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Activate Changes.

Not all changes take effect immediately—some require a restart

After complete your cahges

if Changes on the Servers: Protocols: General page take effect without requiring you to restart the server.

If you made changes on the Servers: Protocols: HTTP page, restart the server.

Comment: @Gavel. Can you please explain little bit more. My understanding is that modifying the above mentioned param could resolve the client browser time out issue? Can I set to 30 mins also?

Comment: I have added steps in my above answer, about setting 30 mins timeout is not look aproprate to me, if its taking 30 min to respose, there could be other issue and need to optimized your business logic code and/or design